# Build native library in JNI folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

I'm testing JNI on Android in Eclipse.

I have a simple Android project with one activity. In Eclipse's project explorer, I added:

- `jni/` folder
- `Android.mk` in the `jni/` folder
- `prng.c` in the `jni/` folder

The source file is named `prng.c` because it wraps Crypto++'s random number generator. Crypto++ is already cross-compiled for ARMv7, so I have `libcryptopp.so` standing by.

When I select *Project → Build Project*, the library is not built. I've confirmed its not built after cleaning the project, too.

```
Android-PRNG$ find . -iname *.so
Android-PRNG$
```

**Question**: Why is Eclipse *not* building the shared object? What else need to be done?

---

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := prng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prng.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**prng.c**

Its basically empty at the moment because I can't get `javah` to run on the Java class file that calls the native methods. I hope to fix that problem next.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

#include <cryptopp/osrandom.h>

static RandomNumberGenerator& GetPRNG()
{
    static AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    return prng;
}
```

Comment: You might try just running **`ndk-build`** from the command line. I forget to what extent Eclipse has NDK support.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. What's the point of using Eclipse if I need to use the NDK? Isn't Eclipse suppose to manage all of these things once the relevant Android.mk and source files are added? Or is this a misunderstanding on my part (and probably many others)?

Comment: "What's the point of using Eclipse if I need to use the NDK?" -- um, the NDK is unavoidable. Trying **`ndk-build`** is a diagnostic step, as you may learn something from the output that you are not seeing from inside of Eclipse. It may also be that you need to [configure the NDK plugin for Eclipse](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin), in case you have not done that yet.  Personally, I don't use Eclipse for building my NDK code; I am merely suggesting avenues for investigation.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. I realize using the NDK is likely unavoidable (modulo using a distro's cross compile tools). I guess my point is, if I have to do it myself with the NDK, then what's the point of adding it to Eclipse? What exactly does Eclipse do besides wastes my cycles :)

Comment: *"Personally, I don't use Eclipse for building my NDK code"* - this is my first time and its not going well. I should probably stop wasting my time and go back to the command line. I'm going to try one more time with a file called `custom_rules.xml` (its referenced from `build.xml`). If that does not work, then back to the command line...

Comment: "if I have to do it myself with the NDK, then what's the point of adding it to Eclipse?" -- again, perhaps you have not configured [the NDK plugin for Eclipse](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin).

Comment: @ CommonsWare  - well, the NDK path is set under preferences. Is there more that needs to be done? Also, `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` (and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`) is set in the environment (per Android tool requirements), so I'm not sure what's wrong. Its like Eclipse and the ADT does not know what to do with a `*.mk` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually very easy with ADT for the last couple of years; it was much worse before. The plugin described in the linked [post](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin) are coming preinstalled; you still need to

1 install NDK

2 set the path to it in `Preferences/Android/NDK` menu

3 right click on your Android project, `Android Tools/Add Native Support`

... and now you are all set.