# Depth limit on System.loadLibrary?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, native-methods

I'm trying to understand an unsatisfied link error. Here's the problem I'm observing.

I have a native C++ library called `libmynative.so`. `libmynative.so` depends on another native C++ library called `libothernative.so`, and the other native depends on STLPort. So my `loadLibrary` chain looks like:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
    System.loadLibrary("othernative");
    System.loadLibrary("mynative");
}
```

The loading of `libothernative.so` is failing due to an unsatisfied link error, and yet the missing symbol is provided by `libstlport_shared.so` (which is already loaded!).

However, if `libmynative.so` wraps `libothernative.a` (note the static library) so that the `loadLibrary` chain looks like:

```
System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
System.loadLibrary("mynative");
```

Then everything succeeds. My `libmynative.so` still needs the symbol(s) provided by `libstlport_shared.so`, but there is no error.

What can explain this behavior? Is there a depth limit to the number of `System.loadLibrary` that can be called?

---

Here are the related questions that don't have answers:

- [How to list shared objects loaded in an Android process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568010/how-to-list-shared-objects-loaded-in-an-android-process)
- [Unsatisfied link error due to libstlport_shared.so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595246/unsatisfied-link-error-due-to-libstlport-shared-so)

And from the Google NDK users group:

- [Unsatsified Link with libstlposrt_shared.so in Activity (_ZNSt12__node_alloc11_M_allocateERj)](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/lFYDJ5QG-EU/wRRwbSnArcgJ)

Comment: How did you link `libothernative.so`? You can use `ndk-depends` to list the libraries it depends upon.

Comment: @Alex - that was it (I figured it out about an hour ago with `readelf`). Someone else wrote the makefile, and the recipe to build the shared object omitted `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`. So `libstlport_shared.so` was not present.

Comment: @Alex - if you want to answer, I'd be happy to award you the points since you beat me to the post.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, it's clear and helpful.

Comment: I understand that the original makefile also includes `LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=true`, desn't it?

Comment: @Alex - I abandoned Android's modified make system because I could not figure out how to make it work under Eclipse (see [Build native library in JNI folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582835/build-native-library-in-jni-folder) and [Build native library with custom_rules.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584177/build-native-library-with-custom-rules-xml)). I went back to building from the command line. Essentially, I build the library from the command line and then copy it into `libs/armeabi/`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track this down to a missing dependency.

Below, when the shared object was built, I used `--sysroot` to include the header and library paths. I also specified `libstlport_shared.so` in `$(LDLIBS)`. However, the command to build the shared object did not include `$(LDFLAGS)` and `$(LDLIBS)` (someone else wrote the makefile).

Readelf showed it was missing:

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -d libcryptopp.so

Dynamic section at offset 0x34472c contains 26 entries:
 Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000003 (PLTGOT)                     0x346e30
 0x00000002 (PLTRELSZ)                   904 (bytes)
 ...
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so]
...
```

---

```
$ make static dynamic
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -pipe -fPIC -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
-I/opt/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/ -c 3way.cpp
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -pipe -fPIC -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
-I/opt/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/ -c adler32.cpp
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -pipe -fPIC -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
-I/opt/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/ -c algebra.cpp
...

arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -pipe -fPIC -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
-I/opt/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/ -shared -o libcryptopp.so
3way.o adler32.o algebra.o algparam.o arc4.o asn.o authenc.o base32.o base64.o
... wait.o wake.o whrlpool.o xtr.o xtrcrypt.o zdeflate.o zinflate.o zlib.o
...
```